# Dropbox won't detect edited files using Remote GIT bare repository folder and ssh

Tags: backup, git, dropbox, hardlink, junction

Here's the situation...

- I develop under windows8 and I have some projects, every project, with a specific local git repository
- For each local repository I have a remote bare repository on my VPS (I use ssh to authenticate and store the repo changes), the VPS mount windows 2003 server using an NTFS disk.

The remote repository is located in:
C:\GIT\REPO\

the "remote" DropBox folder is in C:\Dropbox

I added a junction from C:\GIT\REPO to C:\Dropbox\REPO and Dropbox uploaded everything...

and finally the real problem:

When I push to the remote server using SSH, the modification are saved into C:\GIT\REPO (if I check the system property I can see that some files are altered).
The same thing happens in C:\Dropbox\REPO (because it's a junction)
Oddly Dropbox did not find the altered files and never sync it, unless I manually Pause and then Resume the Sync ifself.
Doing that dropbox reload the index files and perform the sync on the newly files...

is this a bug? how can I bypass that problem? suggestion?
there are any better solution for having always an updaded backup of datas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started out when using Git by syncing up my Git repo with DropBox but have recently switched to hosting private repos in [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) - it allows you to host free, secure, private repos and saves you having to worry about the syncing aspect yourself. It also supports Mercurial :)